# Объединение имени файла и пути

Tags: java

У меня есть путь вроде такого:

```
/home/user/download/
```

И файл, например, `file.txt`. Наверняка должны быть платформонезависимые стандартные методы для объединения пути и имени файла. Простое сложение строк не эффективно, т.к. в пути к файлу может не быть последнего слеша и в разных ОС слеши в разные стороны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто используйте конструктор File

```
File result = new File(new File("/home/user/download/"), "file.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему же? Эффективно. Просто нужно заменить слэш `/` на

```
File.separator
```

Comment: А если путь без слеша ?

Answer (score 1):

без разницы в каком направлении слэши для File

```
    File f = new File("C:\\temp/test.log");
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

результат

```
 C:\temp\test.log
```

Как сказал коллега, всегда старайся использовать `File.separator`